# Oracle Group by query

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I'm trying to run the following query:

```
SELECT parent_id, id, due_date, object_subtype
  FROM amatia_logtask
 WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id_actividad
                       FROM amatia_actividades
                      WHERE id_actividad = '12624'
                         OR id_padre = '12624')
 GROUP BY parent_id id
```

However, I'm unable to understand the error message:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 41
```

Please can you provide an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` clause is a comma separated list of columns or expressions, so you're missing a comma.

You will still get an error since all expressions in the SELECT clause need to be either grouped by or aggregates (using [aggregate functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions003.htm#i89203)).

So you may want to write:

```
SELECT parent_id, id, due_date, object_subtype
  FROM amatia_logtask
 WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id_actividad
                       FROM amatia_actividades
                      WHERE id_actividad = '12624'
                         OR id_padre = '12624')
 GROUP BY parent_id, id, due_date, object_subtype
```

A `GROUP BY` query without aggregates is essentially a `DISTINCT` query, so you can also use distinct here to hint at your intent:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent_id, id, due_date, object_subtype
  FROM amatia_logtask
 WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id_actividad
                       FROM amatia_actividades
                      WHERE id_actividad = '12624'
                         OR id_padre = '12624')
```

Comment: By both this query i got duplicate parent_id. I don't need record which has same parent_id whether other record are same or not.

Comment: @NisargPatel Your requirements were lacking to say the least. If we don't know what you expect, don't expect the solution to be what you want. `DISTINCT` will work accross all columns, not only the first one, so you won't get two exact same sets of `(parent_id, id, due_date, object_subtype)`. What you probably want is to group by `parent_id` only, as suggested by [@OMG Ponies's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14441218/119634).

Comment: what I exactly want is not for distinct it is for that 
Group by is not working in Oracle I have to use any aggregate function so I want group by parent_id without using any aggrigate function on it or any other column....One way to do this is using sub queries but in some case I have to use join also for same and thought not getting right records...Thank you for your Interest...

Comment: @NisargPatel Oracle is quite strict with its `GROUP BY` clause, it may not work exactly like in other RDBMs, but I can assure you it **does** work =). In your case your requirements are incomplete: suppose your query returns two rows with the same `parent_id`, you have to tell Oracle which `id`, `due_date` and `object_subtype` value to retrieve ! Usually, you will use an aggregate function. If you don't want to select those columns, remove them from the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 3):

You have two columns in your `GROUP BY` and no commas between them:

```
group by parent_id, id
                  ^ --- missing this
```

But if you are trying to group on columns, then you can `GROUP BY` all the fields:

```
 group by parent_id, id, due_date, object_subtype
```

Comment: Sorry its not working giving another error-->

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 22

Comment: This is also not working

SELECT parent_id, id, due_date, object_subtype
  FROM amatia_logtask
 WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id_actividad
                       FROM amatia_actividades
                      WHERE id_actividad = '12624'
                         OR id_padre = '12624')
 GROUP BY parent_id

Comment: @OMGPonies you are right. I updated to include a grouping by all fields

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you're after - the following will give you a distinct list of **rows**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.parent_id, y.id, y.due_date, y.object_subtype
  FROM amatia_logtask y
 WHERE y.parent_id IN (SELECT x.id_actividad
                         FROM amatia_actividades x
                        WHERE '12624' IN (x.id_actividad, x.id_padre))
```

Oracle doesn't allow you to omit columns from the GROUP BY, so any that are need to be wrapped in an aggregate function.  IE:

```
SELECT y.parent_id, y.id, 
       MAX(y.due_date) AS due_date, MIN(y.object_subtype) AS object_subtype
  FROM amatia_logtask y
 WHERE y.parent_id IN (SELECT x.id_actividad
                         FROM amatia_actividades x
                        WHERE '12624' IN (x.id_actividad, x.id_padre))
GROUP BY y.parent_id, y.id
```

Comment: +1, although your clever use of the IN operator may prevent the use of indexes =)

Comment: I know "GROUP BY" is not working in ORACLE without using aggregate function in query. But here I don't want to use aggregate function. Please give me solution.

Comment: @OMGPonies :- I want records only group by parent_id. Forgot all other things. can u do for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Plz

```
SELECT parent_id, id, due_date, object_subtype
  FROM amatia_logtask
 WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id_actividad
                       FROM amatia_actividades
                      WHERE id_actividad = '12624'
                         OR id_padre = '12624')
 GROUP BY parent_id,id
```

You Are Just Missing Comma in `GROUP  BY` Clause.Good Luck